# Opening ASP.net development server to world

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the built in web server in Visual Studio to test some pags but I wanted to be able to connect to it from other machines to test out browsers on different platforms.  I was wondering if it was possible to configure that server to listen to an external interface or if I have to throw this over to IIS.  I've turned off the windows firewall so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the default ASP.NET Development Web Server.  You could probably use [Cassini](http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/) if you don't want to use IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SVN and setup a test server to automatically have the SVN updated on the tested server.

What I have done in the past is setup a SVN repository and add my sites into it. And on the test server setup a running copy of the repository and have a scheduled task automatically update it every 5mins. This works great since I dont have to worry about ftping or any thing. Works great since I use VisualSVN and Commenting my changes is easy.